# How to copy artifacts folder to ftp folder in TFS?

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm trying to publish artifacts and it's other folders files as well.I've read all the docs file provide by microsoft from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/ftp-upload) and used them but none of them worked for me. 
I' tried File patterns as

```
** =>which copied all root files to ftp 
**\* => which copied all sub folders file to ftp's root directory.
```

What I've wanted is copy folder to folder in ftp aswell.

```
-artifacts                             ftp
 --a.dll                                --a.dll
 --subfolder                            --subfolder
 ---subfolder_1.dll                     ---subfolder_1.dll

what's happening is
ftp
--a.dll
--subfolder_1.dll
```

It's copying all sub directories file to root directory of ftp.
I've use curl and ftp both giving me same result.
How can i achieve folder to folder copy in TFS 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related **File patterns**, to upload the entire folder content recursively, simply specify `**`.

All you have to do is checking the  **Preserve file paths** in **Advanced** option.

> If selected, the relative local directory structure is recreated under
>   the remote directory where files are uploaded. Otherwise, files are
>   uploaded directly to the remote directory without creating additional
>   subdirectories.
>
> For example, suppose your source folder is: **/home/user/source/** and
>   contains the file: **foo/bar/foobar.txt**, and your remote directory
>   is: **/uploads/**. If selected, the file is uploaded to:
>   **/uploads/foo/bar/foobar.txt**. Otherwise, to: **/uploads/foobar.txt**.

[image]

Comment: This should've come checked by default.